# Outlook Calendar and Slack integration

Tags: microsoft-outlook, slack

I'm using Slack and Outlook Calendar.

The problem I have is, the messages (calendar reminders) that appear in Slack do not match my calendar any more. It's as if Outlook Slack App must cache the calendar and never again update (or at least, not update when I remove an event).

Is there a way to force this re-sync or refresh or update?

Comment: Are you using Outlook desktop client?If so, what's the type of your account on Outloo client. If you have configured your account on Outlook desktop client, please click Send/Receive > Send/Receive All Folder to manually update your calendar.

Comment: Outlook desktop client. Are you saying if I don't click that button (which I never do as it's all instant on Exchange) then it won't sync @Aidan - How do you know this (if it's OK to ask)

Comment: That suggestion does not work @Aidan . A manual send/receive did not update the calendar in Slack...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to 'resync' your calendar is to disconnect it in Slack and then reconnect it again.  This will perform a fresh pull of calendar events.